# Angularjs - Can't read local json file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am building an Angular app. The computer I have is not connected to the Internet.

I tried to read a json file I created locally.

I tried with $http.get and I failed. Got cross origin error.

I read a little bit more and tried the JSONP request.
I can see that i can now access to the json file, but the file is not read as I accepted.

It seems to me that the the browser doesn't understand to parse it as Json file.

What should I do?

Directive:

```
app.directive("Directive", ["Service", function(Service){
return {
restrict: "E",
templateUrl: "views/template.tpl.html",
link: function(scope, element, attributes){
scope.populateInfo = function(){
   var appData = Service.populateData();
    }
   }
  } 
}])
```

The Service:

```
app.service('Service', ['$http', function(http){
    this.populateData = function(){
    var url = "assets/mock.json";
    $http.jsonp(url).then(function(response){
        var result = response.data;

     });
    }
 }]);
```

I do not access to the .then. I got an error "Uncaught SyntaxError": Unexpected token :

mock.json:

```
    {
    "A": [
        {
           "name": "a",
           "id": 1
        },
        {
           "name": "b",
           "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "It seems to me that the the browser doesn't understand to parse it as Json file" — That isn't surprising since you told it to parse it as a JSONP file!

Comment: @Quentin I was just going to post the same answer just the minute you commented though for reference, Please note that `.json` and `.jsonp` are 2 different things [more details](http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/index.html).

Comment: You should to use a jsonp file like this: angular.callbacks._0(
{
    "A": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
)

Comment: I don't understand how to do the angular.callbacks._0. Can you demonstrate it please?

Comment: Someone? I still can't read the file as json....

Comment: Quentin - not exactly a duplicate - as Aviade stated he wanted to 'I tried to read a json file I created locally.' So he can either a. use JSONP and remove browser security measures, or b. Serve the files to himself via http (using http-server, iis, node, tomcat, what-ever-can-serve-http server.)